# Bash process in PowerShell script fails from Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline

I have a PowerShell script that takes parameters and passes them into a shell script. The script works as expected when running it locally, however, when we run it from Jenkins the process is unable to complete.

Here's the simple function:

```
function NexusPull {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [string]$repo,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
    [string]$groupID,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
    [string]$name,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 3)]
    [string]$version,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 4)]
    [string]$app
)

cd C:\Deploy\Nexus

whoami

$nexusScript = 'c:\Deploy\Nexus\nexusPull.sh'
$bash = 'C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe'
$args = "$nexusScript --repo $repo --groupid $groupID --name $name --version $version --app 
$app --silent -pull"


#pulling artifact down from Nexus
Write-Host "running $nexusScript --repo $repo --groupid $groupID --name $name --version $version --app $app --silent -pull"
Write-Host "$(Get-Date -Format G)"

try{
    Write-Host "$(Get-Date -Format G)"
    $process = (Start-Process -FilePath $bash -ArgumentList $args -PassThru -Wait)
    Write-Host "$(Get-Date -Format G)"
}catch {
    throw $_
}

write-host "exit " $process.ExitCode
exit $process.ExitCode
}
```

Jenkins is running as a user that has Admin rights, it runs the PowerShell script and exits 0 but the process doesn't return anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe your Jenkins process is 32-bit Java process? Thus, it probably spawns 32-bit version of Powershell.  As full path suggests, your bash.exe is 64-bit process. So, 32-bit PS may have problem with -Wait switch and exits immediately. This is how CreateProcess and Wait-bunctions behave when 32-bit process tries to run 64-bit process. Make sure your processes on the way from Jenkins to bash are all same kind (32- or 64-bit).

Comment: I've tried both 64-bit and 32-bit bash.exe. It still doesn't go through from Jenkins

Comment: Did you try Start-Process with `-LoadUserProfile`? You may also try to use `-RedirectStandardOutput` or/and `-RedirectStandardError` to see if bash manages to write anything.

Comment: I've tired both of those before and nothing came out of them. 

````$process = (Start-Process -FilePath $bash -ArgumentList $args -LoadUserProfile -RedirectStandardOutput stdout.out -RedirectStandardError stderr.out -PassThru -Wait````

Comment: Running out of ideas... Last (probably) attempt: when trying the script "locally" - do you run it as exactly same Windows user as Jenkins server is running as?

Comment: yep. Same user as the Jenkins service runs as and it works fine. It's the strangest thing.